# How to override django 'unique' error message for username in custom UserChangeForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to override the default "A user with that Username already exists." error message displayed when entering an existing username in my custom `UserChangeForm` form. Django version used: 1.6.1

Here's my code :

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(
        label="User name", max_length=30, regex=r"^[\w.@+-]+$",
        error_messages={
            'invalid': ("My message for invalid"),
            'unique': ("My message for unique") # <- THIS
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

But if I enter an existing username with this code, I still get the default "A user with that Username already exists." message. Note that the custom "My message for invalid" is displayed when entering a wrong username (with invalid characters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently `unique` error message cannot be customized on a form field level, quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields):

> class CharField(**kwargs)
>
> ...
>
> Error message keys: required, max_length, min_length
>
> ...
>
> class RegexField(**kwargs)
>
> ...
>
> Error message keys: required, invalid

So, to summarize, for your `username` field only `required`, `invalid`, `max_length`, `min_length` error messages are customizeable.

You can only set `unique` error message on a model field level (see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L106)).

Also see relevant [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8913).

Also see how [django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70) was made (pay attention to custom `duplicate_username` error message) - custom error message could be an option for you too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

According to [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264505/547733), I ended up creating a custom validation method in my form:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': ("My message for unique")
    }

    username = forms.RegexField(
        label="User name", max_length=30, regex=r"^[\w.@+-]+$",
        error_messages={
            'invalid': ("My message for invalid")
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if self.instance.username == username:
            return username
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
            code='duplicate_username',
        )
```

See the `clean_username` method, taken from [the existing](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70) `UserCreationForm` form to which I added a check to compare with the current user's username.

Comment: Nice - I think that this is the cleanest way to change the message.

Answer (score 3):

at the moment it is possible to override the `unique` error message at the form level:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        error_messages = {
            'my_unique_field': {
                'unique': 'not a snowflake after all'
            },
        }
```