# django auth.login custom error_messages

Tags: django, required

How can I override default error_messages? For example required or invalid_login? I use version 1.9.2.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.conf import settings

anonymous_required =  user_passes_test(
    lambda user: user.is_anonymous(),
    settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL,
    redirect_field_name = 'next')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/', include('products.urls', namespace = 'products')),
    url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace = 'orders')),
    url(r'^calendar/', include('installation_dates.urls', namespace = 'installation_dates')),
    url(r'^supplies/', include('supplies.urls', namespace = 'supplies')),
    url(r'^manufacturer/', include('manufacturer.urls', namespace = 'manufacturer')),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace = 'users')),
    url(r'^login/$', anonymous_required(auth_views.login), name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login/'}, name = 'logout'),
]
```

[SOLUTION] In my opinion, this is the best solution:

part of forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': 'Podane dane logowania są niepoprawne.',
        'required_password': 'Wymagane jest podanie hasła.',
        'required_username': 'Wymagane jest podanie nazwy użytkownika.',
    }

    username = forms.CharField(
        error_messages = {
            'required': error_messages.get('required_username'),
        },
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        error_messages = {
            'required': error_messages.get('required_password'),
        },
    )
```

and urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.conf import settings
from users.forms import UserLoginForm

anonymous_required =  user_passes_test(
    lambda user: user.is_anonymous(),
    settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL,
    redirect_field_name = 'next')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/', include('products.urls', namespace = 'products')),
    url(r'^orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace = 'orders')),
    url(r'^calendar/', include('installation_dates.urls', namespace = 'installation_dates')),
    url(r'^supplies/', include('supplies.urls', namespace = 'supplies')),
    url(r'^manufacturer/', include('manufacturer.urls', namespace = 'manufacturer')),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace = 'users')),
    url(r'^login/$', anonymous_required(auth_views.login), {'authentication_form': UserLoginForm}, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login/'}, name = 'logout'),
]
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You should post your code here, so other can profit from you question. This link will get broken in a while.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override django 'unique' error message for username in custom UserChangeForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264368/how-to-override-django-unique-error-message-for-username-in-custom-userchangef)

Comment: Did you mean that I have to code my own UserLoginForm to override those error_messages? Is it possible to override error_messages using default AuthenticationForm?