# How do I customize the "username already exists" message?

Tags: django

My `forms.py` has a custom user-creation class...

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
 error_messages= {
  "password_mismatch": _("Passwords do not match."),
 }
```

To clarify, I do not know which `error_messages` key corresponds to the one Django spits out when a user tries to sign up with a username that already exists. Which error message do I need to replace for when the user chooses a username that already exists?

Comment: [This SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264368/how-to-override-django-unique-error-message-for-username-in-custom-userchangef) are a bit old: perhaps `'unique'` can be overridden in newer Django versions. But otherwise, see the answer to that question. Also, a related blogpost with more details (referring to this solution) is at http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/05/25/django-customize-error-messages-on-the-user-registration-form

Comment: @Evert I used the method fro the blog post you linked. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the last answer at the linked question mentions 'unique' can be overriden in forms; it's dated August 2017, so less than half a year old, and seems more up to date than the other answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override django 'unique' error message for username in custom UserChangeForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264368/how-to-override-django-unique-error-message-for-username-in-custom-userchangef)

Comment: Strange, I just tried that, but it did not work. I’ll try updating Django and Python packages to see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe override the clean_username() method and Supply your own error_message:

```
error_messages= {

"password_mismatch": _("Passwords do not match."),

"username_exists": _("Username already present`")}



def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")

    try:
        User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        #if the user exists, then let's raise an error message

        raise forms.ValidationError( 
          self.error_messages['username_exists'],  #my error message

          code='username_exists',   #set the error message key

            )
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username # if user does not exist so we can continue the registration process
```