# Django how to change the name of Custom User Model in error messages in a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-errors

I have created a sign up form called `UserRegistrationForm` using `UserCreationForm` in django and have a custom user model name `CustomUserModel`.

When I sign up using wrong credentials, the error messages show "Custom user model with this User name already exists.". I would like it to be something like "Username already exists". How can I do that?

**Forms.py**

```py
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=False)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format='%d/%m/%Y',
            attrs={'type': 'date', 'min': '1900-01-01', 'max': str(timezone.now().year)+'-'+str(timezone.now().month)+'-'+str(timezone.now().day)},
        )
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select, 
        choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('T', 'Transgender'), ('N', 'NonBinary')), 
        initial='N',
    )

    def is_valid(self):
        form = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).is_valid()
        print("*******************************")
        print(self.errors)
        print("*******************************")
        return form
```

**CustomUserModel**

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N', choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('T', 'Transgender'), ('N', 'NonBinary')))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomAccountsManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'date_of_birth']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

Here is a picture to help you understand my problem.

[image: Illustration of form]

The error states "Custom user model with this User name already exists." I want to change this message

Comment: Can you include `CustomUserModel`?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264368/how-to-override-django-unique-error-message-for-username-in-custom-userchangef

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change this error message.

Assuming that you built this Custom User for "Employee",
The message should look like- "Employee with this username already exists."
instead of "Custom user model with this username already exists."

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = YourCustomUserModel
            error_messages = {
                            "your_unique_field":{
                                            "unique":"Employee with this username already exists."
                                                 },
                             }
```

Also see relevant ticket [#8913](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8913).

Answer (score 0):

Add a Meta subclass to your CustomUser class and assign the verbose_name

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_name = forms.CharField(verbose_name="username", max_length=150)

    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"

    ...
```

This should change the message to "User with this username already exists."